# execute function in list every time the variable is called

Tags: python, list

I would like to execute the symbols_list functions every time I call the commands variable. How would I do that? Now it is called only when commands is defined.

```
Bot1Console = ConsoleDialog()

    sl1 = ["arg61a", "arg61b", "arg61c"]
    def symbols_list1():
        l = [str(symbol).lower() for symbol in sl1]
        return l

    sl2 = ["arg70a", "arg70b", "arg70c"]
    def symbols_list2():
        l = [str(symbol).lower() for symbol in sl2]
        return l

    Bot1Console.commands = [
        # All strings have to be in lower case
        ["help"],                           # 00 Help: first element in list
        ["arg10", "arg11"],                 # 01 2 arguments
        ["arg20", ["arg21a", "arg21b"]],    # 02 argument with 2 options
        ["arg30", [float, "arg31b"]],       # 03 argument with 2 options
        ["arg40", str, float],              # 04 type str, type float
        ["arg50", float, str],              # 05 type float, type str
        ["arg60", symbols_list1],           # 06 argument using a function return
        [symbols_list2, "arg71"],           # 07 argument using a function return
        ["arg80", "arg81"],                 # 08 argument using a function return
        ["append", str],                    # 09 append to arg60
        ["exit"]                            # 10 Exit: Last element in List
    ]
```

Comment: You don't call variables; you call functions. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: The sl1 and sl2 lists are subject to change. If I define Bot1Console.commands and later in time the sl1 and sl2 change the Bot1Console.commands variable does not get updated.

I thought that if I use symbols_list function in the list it gets executed each time the commands var is called which is not the case.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't. That's quite a misunderstanding really. If you want to do something when something else changes, you need some way to notify that the change happened. The observer design pattern _may_ be relevant here